# Install Gnome without using yum on centos 4

Tags: linux, centos, wget, gnome, rpm

I'm using CentOS 4.8 , i386.
I would appreciate if any one can help me to install Gnome (or any other GUI) while there is no yum available.

I tried to install yum but since It's a company's server with many things installed on it,
I faced with many problems.
However I decided to find a way to install Gnome without using yum

And please take note:

> I'm a neophyte!

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to mess with a "*company's server with many things installed on it*"? What does it serve? If its a 'server' in the sense that it provides remote services, installing/running GNOME on it might not be the best thing to do. 2. What was the problem you encountered when trying to install GNOME via `yum`? 3. How did you try to install GNOME via `yum`? 4. If you explain those problems and somebody helps you solve them, would you be willing to try the `yum` way again?

Comment: If its a company server- its likely better off without Gnome on it.

Comment: Also, this is better asked on SuperUser. I've voted for a move there anyway.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately they assigned me to a task none of my profession! I want GUI to make it easier to work. anyway, the yum doesn't exist at all. The error is the bash isn't found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try getting the source-code and building it manually?
You can get the code from
    http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/
GNOME also provides a build tool to make the installation easier.

But, as it has already been pointed out - Servers are best managed over command line. It will give you more power and control over what you are doing.